# Problem on Magnetic force on current carrying wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields

I recently came across this question which seems quite interesting

> Two long wires with negligible resistance are shunted at their end by a large resistor R  and at the other ends are connected to a source of constant voltage. The radius of the cross section of each wire is smaller than the distance between the axes of the two wires by a factor of 20 . If the value of the resistance R , at which resultant force of interaction of the wires vanishes, then R is

[image]

I can find the force between the wires due to current I flowing through them but have no idea how to proceed further. I don't understand why the resultant force would become zero too. It would be great if someone could help me out and post a detailed solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a homework-*style* problem, I will not provide the complete answer, I will just address the conceptual question: "How could the resultant force become zero?"

I suspect the idea is that the combination of the two long wires behaves as a capacitor, with each wire being one "plate". As a result, there is an attractive electric field generated between these two wires (indicated on your diagram by the "$E$") which could -- given some value of resistance -- cancel out the repulsive force due to the magnetic attraction of the wires.

So, in order to solve this problem, you need to find out the capacitance of such a configuration, using the simple formula $$C = \frac{A \epsilon_0}{\ell},$$ where $A$ is the area of the "plate" and $\ell$ the separation between them. (The formula above is usually used when the plates are flat. I do not know of any special formula when the plates are "curved" as in this case, but I assume that since the wires are quite far apart, you could approximate the "cylinders" of radius $r$ as bring cubes of width $r$.)

Given the plates are at a fixed voltage, knowing the capacitance would allow you to calculate the total charge on the plates. From here, it's a simple job to find the attractive electric force between two charged wires, and equate it to the repulsive magnetic force to find the critical value of $R$ at which these two are equal.

Good luck!

Comment: Never thought it would be forming a capacitor system, thanks for clearing that out for me. As I looked a little more I found out that two long wire capacitor systems do exist and their capacitance is given by $\frac{\pi \epsilon l}{\ln \frac dr}$ when $d>>r$ where $d$, $r$ are the distance and radius respectively.

Comment: Are you sure you're not talking about a [cylindrical capacitor](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capcyl.html)? Because that's not the same sort of system. But if not, then this should work!

Comment: No, cylindrical capacitor system has a similar sort of a formula but its not that I checked it for two wire capacitor system.

Comment: Ah, interesting, I did not know about that! Feel free to add a link in the comments if you think it'll be useful to someone else looking up this question!

Comment: I saw it on youtube and some other sites where it was derived for some specific question however here is a reliable link which can help out . [1st link](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electricity_and_Magnetism/Book%3A_Electromagnetics_II_(Ellingson)/07%3A_Transmission_Lines_Redux/7.01%3A_Parallel_Wire_Transmission_Line) [2nd link](https://web.mst.edu/~kosbar/ee3430/ff/transmissionlines/LC_of_lines/docs_two_parallel_wires/index.html)